# Android application start-up

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my application,it requires to start the application from the starting activity or the first activity;as the application is authenticated by a login section..

So,whenever the application gets exit;say,via pressing BACK or HOME button,i need to start the application from the login itself...Is there any method to do the same?

I tried a simple technique by overriding the KEYEVENT,and implementing the finish() method inside.It works for the the BACK button;but its not working for the HOME button...

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {

        finish();    
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        finish();    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya got the answer...

I just included the following attribute for the first activity to be displayed all the time,as i said in my question...

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

also include this attribute for the other activities...

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

Just try......

Answer (score 4):

take a look at this:

[activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

basically, everytime your application gets paused, you close the activity so it has to be restarted again. You can do this by overriding the onPause method and closing the activity there

Comment: I tried onPause(),but its still killing only the activity which was active before....

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, one can not override the HOME-button, as it should enable the user to back out of an app at any given point.

Answer (score 1):

when HOME Key Pressed `onStop` is called so you can add `finish();` in  `onStop()` for destory Activity and you can try to use `onUserLeaveHint()` this method also called when user press Home key